# How is the model passed during the collection "add" event?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

In backbone.js, I want to do:

```
initialize: =>
  @collection.on("add", @appendModel(model)) # <- how to correctly write it?

render: =>
  # do some render
  @collection.each(@appendModel())

appendModel: (model) ->
  # append model to $el
```

Currently, i have `@collection.on("add", @render)`, but that redraws the whole collection. I want to just fire `appendModel()`, but I'm not sure how to pass the model in the argument in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you are first invoking the `@appendModel` method with an argument `model`,  and then passing the **return value** to `collection.on`:

```
@collection.on("add", @appendModel(model))
```

You need to pass a reference to the method instead:

```
@collection.on("add", @appendModel)
```

The caller (in this case Backbone) will pass the argument to the method for you.

You might also need to pass `this` (or `@`) as a third argument to the `collection.on` method. This is the *context* argument which tells Backbone that when the callback is executed, the `this` context should be set tot that value:

```
@collection.on("add", @appendModel, @)
```

Or because you're using coffeescript, you can just skip that bit and define the `@appendModel` method with the fat arrow notation, which will ensure that the `this` context is bound to your view:

```
appendModel: (model) =>
```

Comment: > The caller (in this case Backbone) will pass the argument to the method for you. – that's just the answer, thanks a lot! I thought I checked it, but apparently didn't.